# What does saying a verb is "used with/without an object" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, direct-objects

This is a comment a poster made to someone on a discussion,

> Man, why are you hassling me so much this morning? I'm trying to open minds, bro

I wasn't sure about the meaning of *hassle*, and when looking up on Dictionary.com, it shows that the verbal meaning of *hassle* has two senses, one is

> verb (used without object)
>
> - to dispute or quarrel: children hassling over who has the most toys

and the other one is

> verb (used with object)
>
> - to bother, annoy, or harass: I'll do the work, so don't hassle me

I'm not sure which one to apply, because I don't know the meaning of *use with/without object*.

Comment: Plug the definitions you found into the sentence in question and see which one fits:  "*Why are your quarreling me so much this morning?*"  "*Why are your harassing me so much this morning?*"   The first one just doesn't fit.  The second one is the one you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use *with* or *without* an object refers to a verb's *transitivity*.

A verb *with* an object -- specifically, a direct object -- is used *transitively* and is in this circumstance called a *transitive* verb. The direct object is the noun or noun phrase which is affected by the action:

> **Mary walked the cat.** ... *cat* is the direct object.
>   **John is studying English.** ... *English* is the direct object.
>   **Don't hassle me.** ... *me* is the direct object. The sense is "harass".

A verb *without* an object is used *intransitively*, and is called *intransitive*:

> **Mary walked to town** ... Mary doesn't affect another person or thing.
>   **John is studying.** ... John doesn't affect another person or thing.
>   **Boys, don't hassle.** ... Although the boys are presumably affecting each other, they don't affect anyone else. The sense is "quarrel".

Some verbs take two objects, a direct object and an indirect object. The indirect object is the noun or noun phrase which receives the action or for whose benefit is done. These verbs are used *bitransitively*.

> **John gave Mary a book.** ... *book* is the direct object, *Mary* is the indirect object.
>   **Bob told me his story.** ... *story* is the direct object, *me* is the indirect object.

Note that *object* in all of these is *syntactic* category, not a *semantic* category:

> **The story was told by Bob.** ... Although *story* is affected by the action, it is not the *object* of the verb but its *subject*, because this sentence is in passive voice.

Answer (score 0):

By Nature or Type a verb can be:

- TRANSITIVE = It introduces a direct complement, object, accusative, no prepositions required.

> John reads a novel every week

- INTRANSITIVE = It introduces all other complements known as indirect or oblique, genitive, dative, ablative cases. An appropriate preposition is required ,e.g. by, for, with.

> This book was published by Mondadori.

Comment: There are indirect objects, too.