# When does the verb "tell" need a preposition and when doesn't it?

Tags: prepositions

Why doesn't *tell* need a preposition in sentences like the following?

> I told him.　　＝　　I<sub>subject</sub> told<sub>verb</sub> <why no preposition> him<sub>object</sub>

I think it has something to do with it being an **action verb** but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why would it need a preposition? A lot of verbs out there don't need one.

Comment: @MaulikV **need** used preposition, not **tell**

Comment: @Fantasier Why don't they? That's what my question is. What's common in these verbs?

Comment: Oh, I messed up sorry. But... http://www.amazon.com/Tell-Win-Connect-Persuade-Triumph/dp/0307587959

Comment: @snailplane If this question makes no sense then why did you have to use "certain constructions" in your comment? If my question was so senseless, then why didn't you simply say "Tell is used with prepositions"?

Comment: @MaulikV Tell <someone> to win. Why is there no preposition between tell and someone.

Comment: There is another classification of verbs - transitive and intransitive. Transitive verb takes objects directly after them. And "tell" is one of such verb - a transitive verb. And that is why "tell" don't take any preposition.

Comment: I'm afraid if we start having doubts about *Why something happens in some cases*, we'll mess with most grammar books over most of the rules. **It's just like that** and that's why explicitly mentioned in that way i.e. *in some cases* (simply means, **remember** this and don't always stick to the rule).

Comment: @SandeepDhamija The key to understand this is not through the concept of "active verbs", but direct/indirect objects. There are many posts on ELL that discuss direct objects and indirect objects in enough details already. I couldn't find the best one I can remember; however, you can try these answers first: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/707/3281, http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/6555/3281.

Comment: @DamkerngT. very useful questions. They surely make sense.

Comment: @Maulik Exactly. I've VTC as opinion based for precisely that reason. I don't think "why is this so" questions on a language site are a good fit for the StackExchange format. Languages aren't planned, they evolve. Or, as you said more succinctly: it's just like that.

Comment: @starsplusplus Are you serious? If I had assumed "tell" doesn't need a preposition because **it's just like that**, would I ever be able to know the difference between transitive and intransitive verbs? You simply discarded the question because you didn't know the answer. My question is fit for the stackExchange format but are you sure your comment is?

Comment: Actually it's nothing concerning me, but I found your words above rather offensive. I think what they said is actually quite true. In this case, you find an explanation, a distinction that does help, but in some cases I'm afraid the best answer you would receive is *"That's just how people use it"*.

Comment: @Fantasier I would be more than happy to receive "That's just how people use it" as an answer, but calling a query unfit is not right, that too when there exists a valid answer.

Comment: @SandeepDhamija You are actually asking a different question to the one you think you are asking. "**Why** does it sometimes need a preposition and sometimes not?" is just going to be opinion based. What you actually want to know, it seems, is "**When** does it need a preposition and when not?" That is a more answerable and practical question and a much better fit for the SE format. If you edited your question to that it would be at a much lower risk of closure.

Comment: @starsplusplus I'm sorry if I seemed rude earlier. Moving on, If there is a fixed rule regarding transitive verbs, how can the answer be **opinion based**? It has to abide by that particular rule.

Comment: @SandeepDhamija Asking **what the rule is** is not opinion based. Asking ***why* the rule is what it is** IS opinion based. Anyway, with the edit your question is on topic, I think there was just some confusion with your original phrasing.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have the question backward! :) ... you should be asking When does an Indirect Object require a preposition?

(For those unfamiliar with the term, an Indirect Object is a secondary object of a transitive verb: it designates the entity which *receives* the Direct Object or for whose *benefit* the action is performed on the Direct Object.)

> Subject - Verb - Indirect Object - Direct Object

This construction is the standard order in all *di-transitive* situations—those in which the verb takes both an Indirect Object and a Direct Object.

> I told the police my story.  *OR* I told them my story.
>   I gave my son a bicycle.  *OR* I gave him a bicycle.
>   I built my niece a treehouse.  *OR* I built her a treehouse.

Sometimes, however, the Indirect Object has to fall after the Direct Object. When that happens, the syntactic relationships are no longer clear, so the Indirect Object is ‘marked’ with a preposition. There are two circumstances when this happens:

- When the Direct Object is a single pronoun it is too ‘light’ for its role to be clear, so it is moved immediately after the verb:

  > <sup>∗</sup> I told the police it. → <sup>ok</sup>I told it **to** the police.
  >   <sup>∗</sup> I gave my son it. → <sup>ok</sup>I gave it **to** my son.
  >   <sup>∗</sup> I built my niece it. → <sup>ok</sup>I built it **for** my niece.
- When the Indirect Object is ‘heavy’, more than a couple-three words long, it draws focus for too long and it makes it difficult to recognize the Direct object, so it is moved after the Direct Object:

  > <sup>∗</sup> I told the police who came after I called 911 my story.→ <sup>ok</sup>I told my story **to** the police who came after I called 911.
  >   <sup>∗</sup> I gave Richard, my ten-year-old son going to school just a few blocks away, a bicycle. → <sup>ok</sup>I gave a bicycle **to** Richard, my ten-year-old son going to school just a few blocks away.
  >   <sup>∗</sup> I built my niece, my sister's daughter Lily, a treehouse. → <sup>ok</sup>I built a treehouse **for** my niece, my sister's daughter Lily.

  These ‘heavy’ Indirect Objects may not seem all that hard to process; but that is because you are encountering them in writing, where you have the advantages punctuation to clarify structure and of seeing the entire sentence at once. In speech, where your hearer must process your sentence as it emerges, it isn’t so easy, and these constructions are driven by speech patterns.

Two general “rules” are operating here.

- The first is that we like to keep the core constituents of a sentence—the Subject, Verb, Indirect Object and Direct Object—as close together as possible. That drives ‘heavy’ constituents towards the right end of the sentence, where their length provides the least interruption.
- The second is that we like to put the ‘new’ information in a sentence at the right end. That drives pronouns towards the left, because pronouns are almost always ‘old’ information—they usually refer to entities which have already been introduced.